# What is the right way to decode categories array in Swift

Tags: json, swift, api

For example, I have

```
[{
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "numericCode": "004",
    "altSpellings": ["AF", "Afġānistān"],
    "currencies": [{
        "code": "AFN",
        "name": "Afghan afghani",
        "symbol": "؋"
    }]
},
...
```

To get the "altSpellings" and "currencies", how would I build my Model?

```
struct WorldData: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id: String {
        return numericCode
    }
    var name: String
    var numericCode : String
    var altSpellings : Array
    var currencies : ???
}
```

and, if my API object doesn't have an ID, would it be like:

```
var id: ObjectIdentifier
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another struct `Currency` for `currencies` and for `altSpellings` it's just `[String]`.

```
struct WorldData: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let name, numericCode: String
    let altSpellings: [String]
    let currencies: [Currency]

    var id: String {
        return numericCode
    }
}

struct Currency: Decodable {
    let code, name, symbol: String
}
```

Then decode using `[WorldData]`.

```
do {
    let decodedWorldData = try JSONDecoder().decode([WorldData].self, from: data)
    print(decodedWorldData)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Frankenstein! it is working. You might not remember but you also answered my another question not long ago. I really appreciated your quick answer! By the way for my last question, what is the best way to deal with if my API object doesn't have an ID

Comment: You're welcome @DucDang. Yes, I remember when you mentioned it. Also, don't forget to upvote all the SO posts that help you along the way through your development. Keep coding :)

Comment: @DucDang Create an id locally and give it the default value maybe you could use `UUID().uuidString`.

Comment: Hey @Frankenstein, if you don't mind with another question, how would I display those specific values above? for example after calling: ```country : WorlData``` I can only display the String and Int( with extension ) like Text(country.name). And now I'm stuck on others values like currencies, Double ...

Comment: Those values are arrays so you'll have to loop over them using a looping method like `ForEach`.